# Jquery execute two functions on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute functions on click, Below is click button on HTML,

`Insights.init()` will execute on page load will give me some data from server, now with click on button, i need to pass variable to `month` function to filter data, and with click i want to execute all functions inside `Insights()`

```js
    var Insights = function() {
      var initCheckColor = function(vari) {
        console.log(vari);
      }
      var testFunction = function(vari) {
        console.log('test');
      }

      return {
        init: function() {
          initCheckColor();
          testFunction();
        }
      };

    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      Insights.init();
    });

    function month(vari) {
      console.log("hoo");
      return {
        init: function() {
          initCheckColor(vari);
          testFunction();
        }
      };

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="month('test')"> Month </a>
```

Now problem is, i can see "hoo" printed on console when i click on link, but i also want to print it with execution of **initCheckColor(vari)** function, means i want output two times, but i could not output it,

How can i get output two times?

Comment: @Raviteja, vari = "test" which is pass through onClick

Comment: What is `Insights.init()` supposed to do? What should happen on click of button. You code is not self explanatory.

Comment: As per you code, to call `init` of `month` you have to do `month().init()` but that doesn't fix the code, as  `initCheckColor` will be out of scope.

Comment: @sabithpocker, Insights.init() will execute on page load will give me some data from server, now with click on button, i need to pass variable to month function to filter data, and with click i want to execute all functions inside Insights()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** Is with this code

```
function month(vari) {
      console.log("hoo");

      //this block of code
      return {                 
        init: function() {
          initCheckColor(vari);
          testFunction();
        }
      };
      // upto here

    }
```

When you call the `month` function you are returning a object with a property named `init` **Note:** you are just returning a object and not executing the functions within the property. Also other issue is this property is a function which executes two other function, But those functions are not available in the current scope. As they are equal to Private methods for the `Insights` object.

**Solution:** Would be to re initialize the object with data just like how you are doing on page load.

I have fixed your code and added comments in the code where the changes were made.

```js
var Insights = function() {
  var initCheckColor = function(vari) {
    console.log(vari);
  }
  var testFunction = function(vari) {
    console.log('test');
  }

  return {
    init: function(vari) {  // have a input parameter during initialization.
      initCheckColor(vari);
      testFunction();
    }
  };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  Insights.init('something'); // I pass in the string "something" now this will be printed by the initCheckColor function.
});

function month(vari) {
  console.log("hoo");
  Insights.init(vari); // initialize the Insights object by passing in some value.

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onClick="month('test')"> Month </a>
```